# What is the appropriate attire for a workplace fundraising event?

Tags: dress-code

I recently got an internship with a non-profit organization, and tonight they are hosting their annual fundraising event. As an intern, I will be participating in the evening dinner as well as helping out where I can during the event. The evening includes a VIP round table, a notable guest speaker, and a dinner. I'm just not sure what to wear. I've tried contacting my employer, but I haven't received a reply  (I haven't actually started working in the office yet). I was planning on wearing a suit and tie, but is this overdoing it?

Comment: Have you only tried email? A phone call may be in order here.

Comment: Are you officially employed by the organization yet? You say you're going to be working at the event, but haven't started working in the office yet.

Comment: The "correct" answer is definitely to ask the employer, but since you've tried that already, JasonJ's answer is the way to go.

Comment: Try searching online for photos of a similar event last year/some time back, at your company or a similar one. It should give you a clue.

Answer (score 4):

The answer I suspect depends on that type of fundraiser and the venue.  If this was beach volley ball fundraiser then a suit would be overkill.  "VIP round table, Guest speaker, and dinner" sounds more like a formal event.  Unless the invite specifies "Black Tie Gala" or similar, a suit and tie should always be appropriate.  For something like this I would say it is always better to be over dressed than under dressed.  You can always take off your tie if it seems like overkill.